# VBA Script to remove all lines other then my filtered values

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

I am currently in the process of creating a VBA Script where i extract a list of raw data and filter out values Apple, Banana, and Oranges. I then delete all the other rows if it is not the values mentioned above.

So for example i have apple, banana, orange, grape, mandarin, avocado, coconut, lemon, watermelon.

I only want to keep apple, banana and orange in the end. If it has any of the other fruits i want that whole row of information removed.

```
Sub RMWO_Clean()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long


Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Range("Q" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("Q1:Q" & lastRow)


Columns("AF:AF").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AA1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

With rng
.AutoFilter Field:=1,Criteria1:="<>*Apple*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*Banana*"
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

I know that you cannot use

```
Criteria3:=xx
```

I have also tried

```
Criteria1:=Array("<>Apple", "<>Banana", "<>Orange")
```

But this seems to only leave orange behind.

Are you able to let me know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Criteria1:=Array("<>Apple", "<>Banana", "<>Orange")` needs `Operator:=xlFilterValues` operator, and yet won't work with those `"<>"`

so you can fool it by thinking the other way around:

- filter "good" records
- delete all records that are not good

like follows:

```
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Apple", "Banana", "Orange"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) ' reference 'records' only (skip headers)
            Select Case Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells) ' count number of filtered cells
                Case 0 'if no cells to save
                    .EntireRow.Delete ' delete all rows
                Case Is < .Count 'if there's at least one row to delete
                    Set saveRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' store cells to save
                    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filter
                    saveRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide cells to save
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete 'delete visible cells
                    saveRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'bring cells to save visible back
            End Select
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful.
i tried it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with:

[image: img]

I run:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$4")

myRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="<>*Banana*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*apple*"
```

...and I get:

[image: img]

...and then I run:

```
myRange.AutoFilter Field:=1
```

...and I get:

[image: img]

---

I can delete the non-filtered rows with:

```
Rows("2:7").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

---

Putting it all together, you could do something like:

```
Sub DeleteRowsExceptApplesAndBananas()

    Const startCell = "A1"
    Dim rgFilter As Range

    'get range to filter
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rgFilter = Range(.Range(startCell), .Range(startCell).End(xlDown))

        'set filter
        rgFilter.AutoFilter 1, "<>*Banana*", xlAnd, "<>*apple*"

        'delete rows beginning one below startCell's row
        Range(.Range(startCell).Offset(1).Row & ":" & _
            .Range(startCell).End(xlDown).Row).Delete (xlUp)

        'un-filter
        rgFilter.AutoFilter 1
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me that Range.AutoFilter will do what you want it to here, precisely because you can only use two criteria for it.

I'd personally prefer to solve this problem with a loop operation, like so:

```
    Option Compare Text

Sub Macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim col As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    col = "A"
    i = 1
    Set rng = ws.Range(col & i)

    Do

        Select Case rng.FormulaR1C1

            Case "apple", "orange", "banana"
                i = i + 1

            Case Else
                rng.Delete xlShiftUp

        End Select

        Set rng = ws.Range(col & i)

    Loop Until rng.FormulaR1C1 = ""

End Sub
```

The code above assumes that you've already done all the preprocessing you've needed to do to extract your list of fruits, and that that list begins in cell A1 of Sheet1, although you can of course modify that code to put the list anywhere you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 bellow uses a "reverse" **`AutoFilter`**

Version 2, moves all rows to keep to a new sheet, and deletes the old (very fast for a lot of rows)

---

.

**`Version 1`**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteRowsForCriteria()
    Const FILTER_COL = "Q"
    Const To_KEP = "apple banana orange"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1     'Or: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FILTER_COL).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws.Range("AF1:AF" & lr).TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Range("AA1"), _
                                          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                          FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
                                          TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Dim filterCol As Range, toKep As Variant, keep As Range

    Set filterCol = ws.Range("Q1:Q" & lr)
    toKep = Split(To_KEP)

    With filterCol  'Reverse Filter - show all rows to keep ("apple banana orange")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=toKep, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            Set keep = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End If
        .AutoFilter             'Unhide all rows
        keep.Rows.Hidden = True 'Hide all rows to keep ("apple banana orange")
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete   'Delete unwanted (now visible)
    End With
    keep.Rows.Hidden = False    'Unhide rows to keep ("apple banana orange")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

.

**`Version 2`**

---

```
Public Sub DeleteRowsForCriteriaFast()
    Const FILTER_COL = "Q"
    Const To_KEP = "apple banana orange"

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, wsName As String, keep As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheet1    'Or: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, FILTER_COL).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws1.Range("AF1:AF" & lr).TextToColumns Destination:=ws1.Range("AA1"), _
                                           TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                           FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
                                           TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Dim filterCol As Range, toKep As Variant

    Set filterCol = ws1.Range("Q1:Q" & lr)
    toKep = Split(To_KEP)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws1)
    wsName = ws1.Name
    With filterCol
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=toKep, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            .EntireRow.Copy
            ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll           'Paste data on new sheet
            ws1.Delete: ws2.Name = wsName:  ws2.Cells(1).Select
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

---

.

---

**`TextToColumns`** default parameters

- `DataType:=xlDelimited`
- `ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False`
- `Tab:=False`
- `Semicolon:=False`
- `Comma:=False`
- `Space:=False`
- `Other:=False`

Comment: @downvoter - please let me know how I can improve the answer, how is it not answering the question, or what other unintended issues is it causing?